# How do I say "a purple velvet rug"?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs

I know the words I need to use: *un tapis*, *violet* and *en velours*, but I'm not sure whether to place the material first, then the colour (i.e. *un tapis en velours violet*); or the other way round.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Un tapis en velours violet.

would be the most usual word order. The colour refers either to the rug or to the material.

If I said :

> Un tapis violet en velours.

I expect it would not shock anyone. The colour only refers to the rug.

But you'll have to be careful  with a feminine or plural noun because of the agreement.

- > Une moquette en velours violet.

  The colour definitely applies to the material (*velours* is maculine)
- > Une moquette en velours violette.
  >   Une moquette violette en velours.

  The colour applies to the carpet (*moquette* is feminine).

A search with *[chemise en coton bleue](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=chemise%20en%20coton%20bleue&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=)* and *[chemise bleue en coton](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=chemise%20bleue%20en%20coton&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=)* shows more hits for the material being placed first, but the difference is not very large.*

[*Chemise en coton bleu*](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=%22chemise%20en%20coton%20bleu%22&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=#as_qdr=all&q=%22chemise%20en%20coton%20bleu%22) (where the adjective qualifies the material) returns a lot more hits but this figure is not reliable because of all the occurrences where *bleu* is modified (*bleu clair, bleu foncé*, etc.) and therefore invariable. We do not know if the colour describes the item or the material.

<sup>*I have tried the search on something more common than a purple rug...</sup>